# Want to pre-load all the API call on the landing page itself in Angular8. Do we have any default mechanism?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I want to call all the APIs on the landing page itself (instead of calling the APIs on the respective pages due to performance)

Created a service and calling the all **dispatch ngrx actions** to call the APIs.

Is this a better approach or is there any default mechanism?

Any better suggestion/approach?

Comment: [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER)

Comment: https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/making-your-application-feel-faster-by-prefetching-data-with-ngrx#prefetching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also have your effects listening to the [ROOT_EFFECTS_INIT](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/lifecycle#root_effects_init) action. This action is dispatched automatically when the effects were initiated.

```
myFirstEffect$ = createEffect(() => 
  this.actions$.pipe(
     ofType(MyFirstAction, ROOT_EFFECTS_INIT),
     map(action => ...)
  )
);

mySecondEffect$ = createEffect(() => 
  this.actions$.pipe(
     ofType(MySecondAction, ROOT_EFFECTS_INIT),
     map(action => ...)
  )
);
```

Or - if this is too early - implement your own init action and dispatch it in the [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) or when your app is ready.